# Nativescript android: manually initializing new thread

Tags: android, multithreading, nativescript

Since nativescript webworkers are still in their infancy - meaning we cannot access native APIs (its quite a deal-breaker), was trying to manually create a new thread where to drop my sockets in. Code compiles successfully, and runs too.

The `console.log(newThread)` says, that I am in `Thread[Thread-5,5,main]` thread, which is good I guess.
However, when I check on what thread I am from within the new thread itself, it says `CURRENT THREAD: MAIN THREAD -  Thread[main,5,main]`. Any thoughts?

```
var newThread = new java.lang.Thread(
    new java.lang.Runnable({
        run: function(){
            console.log("Running this code in new thread!");

            if( java.lang.Thread.currentThread() == android.os.Looper.getMainLooper().getThread() ) {
                // Current Thread is Main Thread.
                console.log("CURRENT THREAD: MAIN THREAD - ", java.lang.Thread.currentThread());
            } else {
                console.log("CURRENT THREAD: NOT MAIN THREAD - ", java.lang.Thread.currentThread());
            }
        }
    })
);

console.log(newThread);

newThread.start();
```

Comment: You seem to be misinformed there is nowhere stating you cannot access the native apis in a worker

Comment: Indeed I was. Thought this (https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-webworkers) was an official nativescript answer to multithreading, but didn't check the developer. Thanks for clearing that up! (still the above mentioned error will haunt me xD)

Comment: you should take a look at this https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/multithreading-model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are misinformed -- since v2.4, NativeScript has had full webworker support where each worker has FULL access to the entire API.  So you can access the entire Native api from WebWorkers perfectly; the ONLY limit that webworkers have is the standard limit that Android and iOS already have -- which is you don't access UI elements from a separate thread, all UI work has to be done on the main thread.    Beyond that, the sky is the limit.   Please note WebWorkers do spin up a whole new v8 instance since they are running isolated JS code in a new thread; so they use more memory than a straight Android or iOS thread.   But they are cross platform.

Now if you are referring to the NativeScript-webworkers plugin, that plugin (which I am the author) was written a LONG time before official web worker support was added; and yes that plugin has no ability to access any API stuff.    It was a stop-gap measure to add some ability to do threaded work.